# AdMob ads don't open on click

Tags: android, admob, ads, mopub

In my app, AdMob is implemented as a 3rd party network within MoPub. The ads show correctly, but when you click AdMob ads, they don't open. Logs show:

```
I/Ads: Action was blocked because no touch was detected.
```

It seems that click is blocked in the play services library before it bubbles up to the AdView.
Sometimes there is also this message:

```
W/Ads: Received non-success response code 302 from pinging URL: http://app.appsflyer.com/com.indeed.android.jobsearch?....
```

I think this message is not blocking. The first one is blocking imo.

Here is some more information:

- other networks and ads open correctly.
- I tested AdMod without MoPub and ads open correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Optimizely (AB testing tool) is in conflict with AdMob SDK. We use both in our app. Removing Optimizely solved the issue with clicking AdMob ads. If anyone knows details of internal implementation of the two libraries that could cause conflict, please post/comment.